# Calling function in C++ without creating an object

Tags: c++, namespaces

I've read of similar problems to this, but the solutions provided didn't work for me so.

I want to call a function that exists in another class located in a different .cpp file. I don't want to create an instance of the object, I just want to use the function.

My code that tries to call the function:

```
    switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
        cout << "\nDoing stuff\n\n" ;
        Controller::AlbumOps SayHey();
        //SayHey should have run but isn't working
        break;
```

And the function I'm trying to call:

```
#include "Menu.hpp"
#include "Album.hpp"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "AlbumOps.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


    namespace Controller
    {
        static void Controller::AlbumOps::SayHey ()
        { 
        cout << "Hey\n";
        }
    }
```

When I execute the code, the Hey is never printed. I thought the solution was to make the function static but that hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure the code you show compiles?!

Comment: Either make the function static OR move the function out of the class. Can't say for sure without any context, but moving the function out of the class is usually preferable I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The call should be

   ```
           Controller::AlbumOps::SayHey();
           //                  ^^
           //                  double-colon
   ```
2. You should put `static` on the *in-class function declaration*, not the out-of-class function definition (where it means something completely different, "internal linkage"). That is:

   in the header (*AlbumOps.hpp*):

   ```
   // ...
   namespace Controller
   {
       class AlbumOps {
       public:
           // ...
           static void SayHey(); // Note: 'static' here
       };
   }
   // ...
   ```

   and in the implementation file (*AlbumOps.cpp*): either:

   ```
   // ...
   void Controller::AlbumOps::SayHey() // Note: no 'static'
   {
       cout << "Hey\n";
   }
   // ...
   ```

   or:

   ```
   // ...
   namespace Controller
   {
       // ...
       void AlbumOps::SayHey() // Note: no 'static', no repeated 'Controller::'
       {
           cout << "Hey\n";
       }
       // ...
   }
   // ...
   ```

(For the record, what you current

```
        Controller::AlbumOps SayHey();
        //                  ^
        //                  space
```

does is locally declare a function named `SayHey` taking no parameter and returning a `Controller::AlbumOps` (search for "C++ most vexing parse").)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I make the function call as you put it, I get an error: undefined reference to Controller:AlbumOps:SayHey(). I thought I put the static in the right place? In the class before the body of the function? Is that where you are saying?